# rgba() not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I just stuck up with the RGBA() manipulation in jQuery using IE 8

So far i have this:

```
$('.set').click(function (e) {
      var hiddenSection = $('div.hidden');
      hiddenSection.fadeIn()
      .css({ 'display': 'block' })
      .css({ width: $(window).width() + 'px', height: $(window).height() + 'px' })
      .css({ top: ($(window).height() - hiddenSection.height()) / 2 + 'px',
           left: ($(window).width() - hiddenSection.width()) / 2 + 'px'
       })
       .css({ 'background-color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)' })  //Problem here in IE8
       .appendTo('body');
       $('span.close').click(function () { $(hiddenSection).fadeOut(); });
});
```

It works in all other browsers, Don't know why its failing in IE 8 
I got this error!

`Invalid property value` in **jquery.min.js**.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: RGBA wont work in IE8 because it is new to CSS. You could use a PNG24 that is slightly transparent it would work in IE8

Comment: For the future: http://caniuse.com/ really helps a lot with this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple answer: IE8 does not support RGBA properties. It only knows about RGB.

RGBA support was only added in IE9.

Other very old browsers may also not have support for RGBA. However, there aren't many browsers that old that are still in use other than IE8.

There are some ways you could work around this:

- Use a polyfill such as CSS3Pie. This will allow you to specify RGBA background colours in your CSS. You still won't be able to use it directly in JS code as you have it, but you could change the class to deal with it.
- Use a tool like Modernizr to detect whether the browser supports this feature, and provide different functionality if it doesn't.
- Use IE8's `-ms-filter` style to achieve the transparency effect. This allows you to set a range of special effects, including opacity. This is a non-standard IE feature, and is replaced by standard CSS in IE9/10, but is still useful for in certain cases for old IE versions.
- Use a small PNG image with an alpha channel as your background instead. Bit of a shame to be using a background image for a plain colour background these days, but it will achieve the result you're looking for in all browsers.

Comment: Correct. I wonder. OP could use rgba() and at the same time IE alternative for the gradient property?filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#VALOR,endColorstr=#VALOR);

Comment: IE8 (fails), released _March 19, 2009_. FF3 (works), released _June 17, 2008_. Safari 3 (works), released _June 11, 2007_. Google Chrome (any, works), released _September 2, 2008_. ([source](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/))

Comment: @PaulS. - wow, is Chrome really that old? it feels like only yesterday. hmm, now you've made *me* feel old  :-(

Comment: Thanks Spudley.. +1 for the explanation.. i will try to work around those things you suggested.

Answer (score 5):

`rgba isnt supported by ie8.

However, there is a trick for transparency in i.e8

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7F000000,endColorstr=#7F000000);
```

First 2 digit of `#7F000000` are opacity and the next 6 digits are hexa color code.

7f is the equivalent of 50%

So your code should look like :

```
.css({ 'background-color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)' })  //Problem here in IE8
.css({'filter' : 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#50000000,endColorstr=#50000000);'}) //IE Fallback
```

Sources : http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Edit : After Derek Henderson comment, I will not write the code but if you want to add that still only when it'S IE8, check [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)

Comment: I think it's best only to add the IE8 fallback as needed rather than specifying it for all browsers.

Comment: It sure is, but it isnt the question here... I am just showing him that there is a fallback for transparency in IE

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. It should be:

```
rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
```

You were missing the 'a' part.

However, I'm not sure IE8 supports `rgba()` ...then again, jQuery possibly has a wrapper for this?

To be safe, I would try setting a background image in png format that has transparency.

```
.css({ 'background-image': 'http://example.com/myimage.png' })
```

Mikey.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
.css({ 'background-color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)' })
```

you can do this:

```
.css({ 'background-color': 'rgb(0,0,0)', 'opacity': '0.5' })
```

This will work in all the browsers.

Comment: What will happen with the text inside? That's a solution if the element doesn't have any children or text or any border color.

Comment: Nope, sorry. Nice try, but IE8 also doesn't support CSS `opacity`. In addition, `opacity` will affect the element foreground, whereas the original `rgba` code will only affect the background.